# QListView scrollbars are not showing or showing as black

Tags: c++, qt

I cannot figure out why my QListView widget is not showing scrollbars, or sometimes shows them as black. I cannot scroll, not even with up/down keys.

This is what it looks like

[image]

This is the ui portion of the widget

```
          <widget class="FileListView" name="listView">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
          </widget>
```

The autoscroll property in the designer is checked and VerticalScrollBarPolicy/HorizontalScrollBarPolicy are set to ScrollBarAsNeeded

Has any one seem similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found out my problem, I had eventFilter on the listview consuming all the events.